# SQL Server null value issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

When executed the following query it is returning null.

Explanation: the longitude is a `varchar` column, many rows are there having longitude = null but this query did not return anything.

I thing I am missing a minute thing.

```
select * from fb_event where longitude =null
```

Comment: This is not a SQL Server issue - reading an indtroduction into SQL is needed, XXXcoder. Trinary logic is the same in all SQL implementations for a good reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your where clause should read `where longitude is null`.

Null does not equal null, so you must use "is" instead of "=".

Comment: +1 NULL really isn't a value - it's the **absence** of a value - therefore you cannot use the regular value comparison

Comment: More exact as NULL is unknown, comparing one unknown with another can not ever be true - NULL != NULL. NULL also destroys values. SUM with one item NULL is also NULL (unknown).